# CodeBuild can't access ECR repository

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam, aws-codebuild, amazon-ecr

I'd like to use a custom image for my CodeBuild project from my private ECR repository, but the build fails with the following error:

> BUILD_CONTAINER_UNABLE_TO_PULL_IMAGE: Unable to pull customer's
> container image. CannotPullECRContainerError: AccessDeniedException:
> User:
> arn:aws:sts::064791657733:assumed-role/apigateway-apply/AWSCodeBuild-ea2387cb-304d-4d26-8400-5f4601250a71
> is not authorized to perform: ecr:GetAuthorizationToken on resource: *
> because no identity-

This is the terraform code to configure the IAM role policy:
Do I miss anything?

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "apply" {
  name               = local.names.apply_codebuild
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "codebuild.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "apply" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.apply.name
  policy_arn = data.aws_iam_policy.codebuild.id
}

#tfsec:ignore:AWS089
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "apply" {
  #checkov:skip=CKV_AWS_66:Not a sensitive log
  #checkov:skip=CKV_AWS_158:Not a sensitive log
  name              = "/aws/codebuild/${local.names.apply_codebuild}"
  retention_in_days = 365
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "apply" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "logs:CreateLogStream",
      "logs:PutLogEvents"
    ]
    resources = ["${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.apply.arn}:*"]
  }

  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "sts:AssumeRole"
    ]
    resources = local.apply_role_arns
  }
 
   statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "sts:GetAuthorizationToken"
    ]
    resources = ["*"]
  }

  statement {
  effect = "Allow"
  actions = [
    "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
    "ecr:PutImage",
    "ecr:ListImages",
    "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
    "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
    "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
    "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
    "ecr:DescribeImages",
    "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
    "ecr:BatchGetImage",
    "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability"
  ]
  resources = ["arn:aws:ecr:us-west-2:064791657733:repository/apigateway"]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "apply" {
  name   = "CodeBuild"
  role   = aws_iam_role.apply.id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.apply.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "apply-view" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.apply.name
  policy_arn = "arn:${local.partition}:iam::aws:policy/job-function/ViewOnlyAccess"
}

resource "aws_codebuild_project" "apply" {
  #checkov:skip=CKV_AWS_147:Not a sensitive CodeBuild
  name          = local.names.apply_codebuild
  description   = "Responsible for 'apply' of CodeBuild '${local.names.apply_codebuild}'"
  build_timeout = "120"
  service_role  = aws_iam_role.apply.arn

  artifacts {
    type = "CODEPIPELINE"
  }

  environment {
    compute_type                = "BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL"
    image                       = "064791657733.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/apigateway:latest"
    type                        = "LINUX_CONTAINER"
    image_pull_credentials_type = "SERVICE_ROLE"
  }

  logs_config {
    cloudwatch_logs {
      group_name = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.apply.name
    }
  }

  source {
    type = "CODEPIPELINE"
    buildspec = templatefile("${path.module}/buildspecs/sbr.yml", {
      SCRIPT           = local.apply_script
      NAME             = var.name
      RUNTIME_VERSIONS = var.runtime_versions
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you set codebuild up to use this role instead of the codebuild role? The codebuild role can only access public repositories.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/codebuild_project#image_pull_credentials_type

Comment: Yes, the project was set up to use CODEBUILD as credential type. 
  environment {
    compute_type                = "BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL"
    image                       = "064791657733.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/apigateway:latest"
    type                        = "LINUX_CONTAINER"
    image_pull_credentials_type = "CODEBUILD" --> "SERVICE_ROLE"
  }

Comment: You are missing the `ecr:GetAuthorizationToken` permission.